# LuisRecognizer Constructor is deprecated. Please use LuisRecognizerOptions

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using a Microsoft bot builder SDKv4 for creating a Chat bot using LUIS.ai for getting the top intent.
I used the following code to configure luis in my .net core 2.1 project.

```
public BotServices(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Read the setting for cognitive services from the appsettings.json
        Dispatch = new LuisRecognizer(new LuisApplication(
            configuration["LuisAppId"],
            configuration["LuisAPIKey"],
            $"https://{configuration["LuisAPIHostName"]}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"),
            new LuisPredictionOptions { IncludeAllIntents = true, IncludeInstanceData = true },
            true);
    }
```

But I am getting this warning : "LuisRecognizer,LuisRecognizer ... is obsolete: ... please use LuisRecognizer(LuisRecognizerOptions recognizer)".

I followed this Microsoft tutorial to set it up. Even following the tutorial also gives the same "obsolete" error at line:

```
Dispatch = new LuisRecognizer(luisApplication);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-bf-v4

How can I configure luis in this case?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial appears to be out of date.  Please refer to the samples for the most up-to-date code.  https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/FlightBookingRecognizer.cs#L27

```
var luisApplication = new LuisApplication(
    configuration["LuisAppId"],
    configuration["LuisAPIKey"],
    "https://" + configuration["LuisAPIHostName"]);

var recognizerOptions = new LuisRecognizerOptionsV3(luisApplication)
{
    PredictionOptions = new Bot.Builder.AI.LuisV3.LuisPredictionOptions
    {
        IncludeInstanceData = true,
    }
};

Dispatch = new LuisRecognizer(recognizerOptions);
```

With app setting:

```
"LuisAPIHostName": "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
```